# Insert submitted form content to DB using drupal_write_record

Tags: module, form-api, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert submitted form content to DB using drupal_write_record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313648/insert-submitted-form-content-to-db-using-drupal-write-record)

I'm new in drupal and what I trying to do is my first module so hope you understand me. 
I created a registration module, and want to connect it to database through **[drupal_write_record](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6)** but I don't know exactly how to do it. I read how to use this method from drupal website but still couldn't do it.

Can you please help me manage that?

Here is how my module looks like:

```
function my_module_menu() {
$items = array();
$items['my_module/form'] = array(
    'title' => 'Contact Information',
    'description' => 'Contact Information',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'access callback' => true,
    'weight' => '10',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' =>  MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
$items['my_module/list/1'] = array(
    'title' => t('Contact list'),
    'page callback' => 'my_module_form_list_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
);
return $items;
}
function my_module_perm() {
return array('access my_module content', 'access administration pages');
}

function my_module_help($path, $arg) {
$output = '';  //declare your output variable
switch ($path) {
case "admin/help#my_module":
    $output = '<p>'.  t("Displays information about site") .'</p>';
    break;
}
return $output;
}
function my_module_form($form_data) {
$form['contact_information'] = array(
    '#value' => variable_get('contact_form_information', t('Please fill in all fields.'))
);
$form['first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First name'),
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['last'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last name'),
    '#maxlength' => 20,
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['street'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Street Address'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
); 
$form['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('City'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
); 
$form['postal'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Postal Code'),
); 
$form['state'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('feed_item_length','chisinau'),
    '#options' => array(
    'chisinau' => t('Chisinau'), 
    'balti' => t('Balti'), 
    'cahul' => t('Cahul')),
); 
$form['phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Business Phone'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
); 
$form['ext'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('ext'),
); 
$form['mobile'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Mobile'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
); 
$form['home_phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Home Phone'),
);
$form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
);
$form['clear'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Cancel'),
    '#validate' => array('my_module_my_form_clear'),
);
return $form;
}

function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_data){
global $user;
    $data = array(
        'id' => $user->id,
        'first' => $form_data['values']['first'],
        'last' => $form_data['values']['last'],
        'street' => $form_data['values']['street'],
        'city' => $form_data['values']['city'],
        'postal' => $form_data['values']['postal'],
        'state' => $form_data['values']['state'],
        'phone' => $form_data['values']['phone'],
        'ext' => $form_data['values']['ext'],
        'mobile' => $form_data['values']['mobile'],
        'home_phone' => $form_data['values']['home_phone'],
        'email' => $form_data['values']['email'],
    );
drupal_write_record('my_module', $data ,'id');
drupal_set_message(t('Information has been saved to the database')); 
}
```

**working with this method, but is not what I need:**

```
function my_module_form_submit($form_id, &$form_data)  {
db_query("INSERT INTO my_module (id, first, last, street, city, postal, state, phone, ext, mobile, home_phone, email)
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
$form_data['values']['first'],
$form_data['values']['last'], 
$form_data['values']['street'],
$form_data['values']['city'],
$form_data['values']['postal'], 
$form_data['values']['state'],
$form_data['values']['phone'],
$form_data['values']['ext'], 
$form_data['values']['mobile'],
$form_data['values']['home_phone'],
$form_data['values']['email']); 
drupal_set_message(t('Information has been saved to the database')); 
}
```

My_module.install file :

```
function my_module_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('my_module');
}

function my_module_uninstall() {
 drupal_uninstall_schema('my_module');
  } 

function my_module_schema(){
  $schema = array();
  $schema['my_module'] = array(
  'description' => 'My Module table.',
  'fields'=>array(  
  'id'=>array(  
  'type'=>'serial',  
  'unsigned'=>TRUE,  
  'not null'=>TRUE  
  ),  
  'first'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),  
  'last'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ), 
  'street'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  'city'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  'postal'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  'state'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  'phone'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  'ext'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ), 
  'mobile'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  'home_phone'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  'email'=>array(  
  'type'=>'varchar',  
  'length'=>255,  
  'default' => 'NULL',  
  'null'=>TRUE  
  ),
  ),  
   'primary key'=>array("id"), 
  );
  return $schema;
  }
```

What is wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: I deleted one submit button and now I have just one left, after I hit it, I receiving confirmation message: "Information has been saved to the database".

Can you please guide me how to use wathdog method here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is this message being displayed only after removing one of the submit buttons or was it shown even before? and does the `my_module` table have any record inserted in it now? watchdog is merely for logging to the db instead of displaying a message to the screen like drupal_set_message

Comment: Are you updating or inserting? I can't see `'id' => $user->id,` in your Form array, is it the primary key of the table? If that is the case, you'll need to use the third parameter when you call drupal_write_record. Have you created the table `my_module` and does it include all your fields? *Edit: I'm quite new to StackExchange. Should I have added this as a comment to the post instead? Since it isn't really an answer.*

Comment: 'drupal_set_message' was also displyed before. my_module, has one record now, I add it with the method that I just upated above.

Comment: I trying to add(insert) records to DB. Please check above how my My_module.install file looks like. 
In 'my_module' table my first row is auto_incrementing ID

Comment: @hampusn, what should to be the third parameter for `drupa_write_record` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of `drupal_write_record` should be an array of the primary ids. In your case (if the field id is really the primary key.) should be `array('id')`. However, since i cannot see the whole hook_schema function I can't say if you have a primary key set?

Are you using Drupal 7 or Drupal 6? Drupal 6 also requires you to have a `hook_install()` with a function call to `drupal_install_schema('my_module')`.

Read more about drupal_write_record here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7.

Comment: I using drupal 6, above I just updated my full schema method.
I started once again, I removed table from db and disabled module. After that, I enabled back my module but `my_module.install` didn't create table in db. I trying to understand where is the mistake.