# How do you create a Drupal Form Module which connects to an external Database

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin, drupal-8

**Drupal 8:**
I'm wondering how to go about creating a Form Module which connects to an external Database(situated on PHPMyAdmin), rather than the Drupal 8 Database. I'm rather new to Drupal and have not been able to find any examples of such that may work for me.

Any help is much appreciated.
This question is very much Drupal 8 specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert submitted form content to DB using drupal\_write\_record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317031/insert-submitted-form-content-to-db-using-drupal-write-record)

Comment: Not a duplicate as my question is about Drupal 8 and from the reading I have done of the other question its for earlier versions, before the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In settings.php

```
$databases = array();
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  // Drupal's default credentials here.
  // This is where the Drupal core will store its data.
);
$databases['my_other_db']['default'] = array(
// Your secondary database's credentials here.
// You will be able to explicitly connect to this database from you 
   modules.
);
```

In your module file

```
    db_set_active('my_other_db');
    // Run queries
    // Change back to your DB
    db_set_active();
```